# Factory Method Pattern using Generics-C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics

Just I am learning Generics.When i have an Abstract Method pattern like :

```
//Abstract Product
interface IPage
{
    string pageType();
}

//Concerete Product 1
class ResumePage : IPage
{
    public string pageType()
    {
        return "Resume Page";
    }
}

//Concrete Product 2
class SummaryPage : IPage
{
  public string pageType()
  {
    return "SummaryPage";
   }
}

//Fcatory Creator
class FactoryCreator
{
   public IPage CreateOnRequirement(int i)
    {
      if (i == 1) return new ResumePage();
      else { return new SummaryPage(); }
    }
}


//Client/Consumer

void Main()
{

  FactoryCreator c = new FactoryCreator();
  IPage p;
  p = c.CreateOnRequirement(1);
  Console.WriteLine("Page Type is {0}", p.pageType());
  p = c.CreateOnRequirement(2);
  Console.WriteLine("Page Type is {0}", p.pageType());
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**how to convert the code using generics?**

Comment: What is your end goal?  Why do you have the need for generics at all?

Comment: Maybe he wants to learn how to use Generics in a Factory Pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement the method with a generic signature and then create the type passed into the type parameter.

You have to specify the `new()` condition though.
This means it will only accept types that have an empty constructor.

Like this:

```
public IPage CreateOnRequirement<TCreationType>() where TCreationType:IPage,new()
{
    return new TCreationType();            
}
```

Comment: where TCreationType : new(), IPage

Comment: Thanks Simon for spending your time.

Comment: new() constraint must be  placed at last  i mean IPage,new()  instead 
new(),IPage.

Comment: Edited according to comments.